# React Native App lags in release build only

Tags: react-native

This is a fun one. My app works perfectly in debug mode, but lags everywhere in release mode (transitions, touches, loading, etc.). Usually the release build is faster than the debug build. I do not have "debug JS remotely" turned on, so it's not because of Chrome running the debug build that made it faster.

I profiled the app in XCode/Instruments and it shows a bunch of CFStrings rack up in memory until it runs out and crashes. Unfortunately, pausing the debugger in Xcode doesn't show the JS code, so I can't inspect if something is stuck in an infinite loop.

Edit: I have tslint to enforce no `console` calls and `transform-remove-console` Babel plugin enabled to remove all `console` calls inside other libraries

Do you have ideas on
1. what would make release mode be slower than debug mode in general?
2. how to track down what JS functions are being called in the release build? (when there isn't shake-to-debug option)
3. if it is possible to inspect what is in the CFStrings inside Instruments?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a lot of ```console.log```'s?

Comment: like @Wainage said, any `console` statements have the potential to cause huge bottlenecks. This is worth a read: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance

Comment: I have tslint to enforce no `console` calls and `transform-remove-console` Babel plugin enabled to remove all `console` calls inside other libraries

Comment: @EdmondC Did you manage to find the reason behind this? I'm facing a similar issue!

Comment: @GauravOjha, for my project, there are subscriptions to data changes. On staging, there weren't many; however, on production, these events come in bursts. The event handler triggers expensive redraws. Solution was: 1) batch up those events and redraw once, 2) optimize change detection for components to reduce the number/depth of redraws, and 3) profile all `for`/`while` loops and event handlers etc., then apply slicing to give "breathing room" to others, i.e. given a list of 10,000 items, queue up 200 at a time (w/ `setTimeout` or `rxjs`), allowing UI events to respond between frames

Comment: It's really cool. I have exactly the same problem 

Comment: My app performed well on 0.59.9 on both platforms.
After upgrading to 0.62.2 it is much slower on android, still works well on iOS.

I am referring only to release mode, I don't care too much about debug mode performance.